# meteor 1.2.1, okgrow:promise not working on server side

Tags: http, meteor, promise

After installing okgrow:promise, I call HTTP.getPromise in one of my Meteor.methods placed in the server folder, but I got the error "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getPromise'". I setup breakpoints at both serer and client code, and noticed on the server, nothing has been added to the HTTP or Meteor object, but on the client, they are added (getPromise, deletePromise...).

Is this by design? And what is the best way to call HTTP.get asynchronously on the server side in Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is by design: https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-promise/blob/master/package.js#L14.

```
...
api.addFiles('wrapPromise.js', 'client');
...
```